# Javascrtip bind, does it make a deep copy of `this`?

Tags: javascript, environment-variables, prototype

I am new to prototype, and I just made a simple example that won't work. From the code below its obvious what I want - a counter. But for some reason the output is always `5`, I guess that the `bind` is making a deep copy of the `this` object, which is then bound to the function. There is an obvious solution where I make everything public, but I would like to know if there is a more elegant solution. (Or you may correct my and tell me that there is no deep copy, but some other bug). The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) didn't help me.

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="click" onclick="javascript: doTest();" />
        <div id="canvas"></div>
        <script>
            var ClassA = function (position, element) { // constructor
              this.field1 = position;
              this.target = element;
            };

            ClassA.prototype = function () {
              // private functions
                var _aPrivateMethod = function(){
                    console.log(this);
                    this.field1 += 1;
                    return this.field1;
                };

                var _aPublicMethod = function(){
                    this.target.innerHTML = _aPrivateMethod.bind(this)();
                };

                return { // interface
                    constructor: ClassA,
                    aPublicMethod : _aPublicMethod
                };
            }();

            function doTest() {
                var obj = new ClassA(4, document.getElementById('canvas'));
                obj.aPublicMethod();
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The anonymous function assigning to `ClassA.prototype` never uses (or gets) its `self` argument. Also, you should wrap immediately-invoked functions in parentheses for readability.

Comment: Sorry guys, silly mistakes while trying out things before posting that I didn't clean up. Thanks for telling me.

Comment: I think you don't fully understand `.bind`. It returns a new function that calls the old function with the bound `this`. What you're doing is setting `innerHTML` to that *function*. You should rather call the bound function (or just use `.call(this)`).

Comment: Yep I don't understand `bind`. And I also tried `.bind(this)();` no luck. The main issue what the fact that I initiated new objects every time in the `doTest()`. See my comments to the answer - And Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a number of issues. First you call `doTest` each time. A new object is created on each click, so there's no way to increment `field1`.

As I understood you want `field1` to be private. In the way you initialize it, it cant be private. You can do something like:

```
function Person() {
   var counter = 0;
   this.increment = function () {
       return ++counter;
   }
}
```

In that way you can't access the `counter` from outside the function scope.

Another issue is that you don't call the private method with the right context. You should use `_aPrivateMethod.call(this)` as pimvdb have mentioned.

Here is an example of:

```
function Person() {

    var age = 0;

    function incrementAge() {
        return ++age;
    }

    function eatCake() {
        console.log('Yey. I\'ll eat cake!');
    }

    this.birthday = function () {
        eatCake();
        return incrementAge();
    }
}

var p = new Person();
p.birthday(); //'Yey. I'll eat cake!', returns 1
p.birthday(); //'Yey. I'll eat cake!', returns 2
```

In that way `eatCake`, `incrementAge` and `age` are all private because of the functional scope.
The bad thing in the example is the way I've declared the function `birthday`. For each instance of `Person` a new copy will be created.
The right way is:

```
Person.prototype.birthday = function () { ... }
```

My declaration is not like this one because I want to use a private data members. Actually not private just local for the function (`age`, `eatCake`, `incrementAge`).
There's no way to access them from a function which is declared in the prototype, so that's why for the example above I've choose that approach.

Comment: Well I have to wait to accept you answer, but thanks. I missed the fact that I init a new object every time - works fine now! :)

Comment: Great. I've added one more example with inheritance. I hope that it's not too complicated. If there's something unclear in it please let me know.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. For your (and future readers) information: declaring functions in the constructor, makes them private, but a copy of them will be made for each instance. Not good if many are initiated.